# What is the role of the curly braces when a module is required?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In this code snippet:

```
const {set} = require("lodash");
```

What does the {} do ?

Comment: It will import specific object/function from the module and initialize it with the same name

Answer (score 1):

It's [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

It's equivalent to

```
const set = require('lodash').set
```